# Send push notification From firebase by using Firebase cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification by the following way:

```
exports.sendPushNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/chat_rooms/{id}').onWrite(event => {

console.log(event);
const original = event.data.val();
const reciverId = original['receiverID'];
const text = original['text'];
const senderName = original['senderName'];
var path = 'fcmToken/' + reciverId;

const payload = {
notification: {

title :senderName,
body: text,
badge:'7',
sound:'default',

    }
};
return admin.database().ref(path).once('value').then(allToken => {
    if (allToken.val()){
      var firebaseReceiverID = allToken.val();
      var firebaseToken = firebaseReceiverID['firebaseToken'];

     return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(firebaseToken,payload).then(response => {
     });
      };
   });
 });
```

My firebase database structure is[image] like this:
    how to send push if any child is added under chatroom(to detect the path)

Comment: is the current push notification being sent? what are you getting here `console.log(event);`?

Comment: when new chat_rooms is added then it execute otherwise it is not executed I want to execute when msg is added uder chatroom

Comment: yes thats correct, so what is the problem? Thats the purpose of onWrite it get triggered when anything is added at that location. Where is msg, in the database?

Comment: Hi peter thanks, the problem is that how to get the latest msg added under chat room I thin the structure should be like this

functions.database.ref('/chat_rooms/{PerticularChatRoom_id}/{id}').onWrite(event => {

} 
here how to fetch Perticular chat room id where msg is added

Comment: functions.database.ref('/chat_rooms/{PerticularChatRoom_id}/‌​{id}').onWrite(event => { }  here perticular chat room id how to get it

Answer (score 2):

`onWrite` is a database trigger, so everytime you add data under the location that you specify it will be triggered.

Now if you want to get the id you can do this:

```
export.sendPushNotification=functions.database.ref('/chat_rooms/{PerticularChatRoomid}/‌​‌​{id}').onWrite(eve‌​nt => { 

console.log(event);
const chatroomid=event.params.PerticularChatRoomid;

}
```

This way you will be able to get the `PerticularChatRoomid` from the database.

To get the values of the wildcards `{id}`, always use `event.params`

More info in this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events